# Failed to resolve Gradle dependency

Tags: javascript, java, android, gradle

I am using a gradle dependency and have been for the past 12 months. All of a sudden today, it can not resolve.

I have tried changing the version, cleaning my build, reinstalling Android SDK's etc. but all to no avail.

I was hoping someone could help me in resolving this issue. The error is below:

[image: Android Error Log]
[image: Android Error Log 2]

Gradle File Below:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "OMMITED-FOR-SECURITY"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 7
        versionName "1.0.3"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.SplashActivity.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        renderscriptTargetApi 23
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
        multiDexEnabled true

        ndk {
            abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86', 'arm64-v8a'
        }

        //Brandon's Added Config
        manifestPlaceholders = [onesignal_app_id: "583f96e8-3cec-416e-ad0e-7bdef470a6a7",
                                // Project number pulled from dashboard, local value is ignored.
                                onesignal_google_project_number: "REMOTE"]
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        flatDir {
            dirs '../aar'
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
    }

    buildDir = 'Build'
}

dependencies {

    //File Tree
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    //Android Dependencies
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

    //Parse Dependencies
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.15.7'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-applinks:1.4.0'
    compile 'com.parse:parsefacebookutils-v4-android:1.10.3@aar'
    compile 'com.parse:parseui-login-android:0.0.1'
    compile 'com.parse:parseui-widget-android:0.0.1'

    //Cloud Hosting Libraries
    compile 'com.dropbox.core:dropbox-core-sdk:3.0.2'
    compile('com.microsoft.aad:adal:1.2.2') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    }
    compile 'com.onedrive.sdk:onedrive-sdk-android:1.2.1'

    compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.8'
    compile 'com.ogaclejapan.arclayout:library:1.1.0@aar'

    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.10.0'

    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.github.florent37:camerafragment:1.0.4'
    compile 'com.box:box-android-sdk:4.0.8'
    compile 'com.eclipsesource.minimal-json:minimal-json:0.9.1'
    compile 'com.kyleduo.switchbutton:library:1.4.5'
    compile 'net.danlew:android.joda:2.9.9'
    compile ('com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:3.3.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    }
    compile 'com.miguelcatalan:materialsearchview:1.4.0'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1'
    compile 'com.github.axet:android-library:1.1.3'
    compile 'com.chauthai.swipereveallayout:swipe-reveal-layout:1.4.0'
    compile 'com.linsea:universalvideoview:1.1.0@aar'
    compile 'com.devbrackets.android:exomedia:4.0.3'
    compile 'com.flurgle:camerakit:0.9.18'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'homhomlin.lib:ptrrv-library:1.3.1'

    //Butter Knife
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.5.1'
    compile 'com.beloo.widget:ChipsLayoutManager:0.3.7@aar'
    compile 'com.github.oxoooo:touch-image-view:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1'

    //DMSDK Libraries
    compile(name: 'dms', ext: 'aar')
    compile(name: 'audiohelper', ext: 'aar')
    compile(name: 'camerahelper', ext: 'aar')

    //Brandon's Added libraries
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'com.github.michael-rapp:android-material-dialog:4.0.3'
    compile 'com.iceteck.silicompressorr:silicompressor:2.0'
    compile ('com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.6.0, 3.99.99]') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
    }
    compile 'com.orhanobut:dialogplus:1.11@aar'
    compile 'com.thefinestartist:finestwebview:1.2.7'
    compile 'info.hoang8f:android-segmented:1.0.6'
    compile 'com.github.wseemann:FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever:1.0.14'

    //IMG.LY Libraries
    compile 'ly.img.android:photo-editor-sdk:5.0.0-beta'

    //HTML Libraries
    compile 'jp.wasabeef:richeditor-android:1.2.2'
    compile 'org.sufficientlysecure:html-textview:3.4'

    //Play Service Libraries
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.2.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.2.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:11.2.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.2.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.2.2'

    //Firebase Libraries
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:11.2.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.2.2'
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.2.2"
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.2.2'

    //Messaging Libraries
    compile 'com.github.stfalcon:chatkit:0.2.2'
    compile 'org.cryptonode.jncryptor:jncryptor:1.2.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

My project wide build file is as follows:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.7.0'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots" }
        maven { url "https://artifactory.9elements.com/artifactory/imgly" }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: If it's of any significance, this has only started happening since installing OSX High Sierra

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have figured out the issue.

The issue was that the component author changed their IP address and failed to inform the community.

Gradle keeps a cache of plugins and I had to clear the cache in order to make gradle recognise the new IP address. To do this I did the following:

**In Android Studio:**

1. File > Invalidate Caches / Restart...
2. Invalidate and Restart

**In Android Terminal (OSX):**

./gradlew cleanBuildCache

**In Android Terminal (Windows):**

gradlew cleanBuildCache

Answer (score 0):

This is going to sound weird, but you should check that your system clock is set correctly, including the proper time zone.

If your system time is correct, you might need to nuke and re-install your JVM.

Your build is failing because Gradle can't reach the artifact repository. When it tries to connect, it's throwing this error:

```
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: 
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: 
unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

That's Gradle telling you that the TLS handshake between Gradle and the artifact repository is failing.

There's a few reasons this could happen:

1. Somehow your trust store got zapped so the JVM doesn't recognized any SSL certs, including CA-signed ones.
2. Your system time is so bonkered that the validation routine thinks the site's SSL certificate is expired, or hasn't taken effect yet.
3. You're behind a TLS-aware proxy but you don't have the proxy's cert in your trust store.
4. The repo's SSL certificates are in fact hosed (in which case it'd be down for everyone, not just you)

You can rule out most of these by pointing your web browser at the repository download URL shown in the error. If the file downloads, you know it's not your system time or the server's SSL certificates.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. After pointing my browser to https://artifactory.9elements.com/artifactory/imgly/ly/img/android/photo-editor-sdk/5.0.0-beta/photo-editor-sdk-5.0.0-beta.pom it downloaded without a hitch. 

So now I'm wondering, should I remove Java and reinstall it? and If so, how would I go about it?

Comment: That's good. That suggests a problem at the JDK level.

I don't suppose you did any hacks to system startup scripts to set JAVA_HOME system-wide? Because if you did, those hacks probably got reverted in the upgrade process.

Failing that, maybe nuke Java entirely and re-install the latest JDK fresh. If it's a nuked trust store, that should fix it.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, I've never modified the JDK or Java install so i'm safe there.

I have removed the JDK and Java and reinstalled JDK8u144 and still getting the same error after restarting the Mac

Comment: I notice that their artifactory SSL cert is issued by Let's Encrypt. I think their cross-signed cert isn't playing nice with the JDK's default trust store.

Grab the root certs from https://letsencrypt.org/certificates/ and import them into `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts` using `keytool` and I think it will get you sorted.